# How passport.authenticate() determine successRdirect or failureRedirect?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I beginner to nodejs and trying to apply authentication using (passport,passport-local) and using local strategy.in local strategy i check email and password and compare it with database record.if email and password is correct I return done(null, user) call back.Then in passport.authenticate()
how it determines to redirect to failureRedirect or successRedirect?

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',
{
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
}

));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Authenticating with `passport`. Strategies require what is known as a ***verify callback***. The purpose of a verify callback is to find the user that possesses a set of credentials.

You can return 3 types of callback result

1. `done(err)` which just returns if error occurs while processing.
2. `done(null, false, {custom Message})` which means no `error` but either `email` or `password` didn't matched.
3. `done(null, user)` which means no `error` and successful authentication

based on what is returned failureRedirect or successRedirect is decided

[More Info Here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/)